# Image not coming top of another one after giving z index

Tags: css, z-index

I am trying to modify the design of a web site . There is an image slider and I would like to show a circle log above of the header section. Now the image is displaying , but it is broken and not displaying in full size , Please check the site [here](http://gainvidya.com/atm/singletour.php)  and see that green rounded button .

I have used the following codes

```
<div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom st-div">
    <div style="height:13px;">
        <div style="margin-top: -10px;height:21px;"> <span> 
                <img  src="images/850.png" width="60" alt="l" style="margin-top:-15px;z-index:1000;"/>
            </span>    
            <h6 class="st-ro" style="margin-top: -40px;">ROMANTIC GETAWAY</h6> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me , I would like to display the green rounded logo full size there .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add a CSS `position:`  declaration (relative, absolute etc) in order for `z-index` to have any effect